# Set default empty array in laravel migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I want to set empty array for column interests. I've added field as json and cast it as array in my model. Below are my code snippets :

```
/**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('db_invitations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            if(!Schema::hasColumn('db_invitations','interests')){
                $table->json('interests');
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('db_invitations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            if(Schema::hasColumn('db_invitations','interests')){
                $table->dropColumn('interests');
            }
        });
    }
```

Also in model :

```
/**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'interests' => 'array'
    ];
```

So what i need to do to show default [] in interests column ?

Comment: `->default('[]')` maybe? my question is, why would you do that instead of keeping the NULL value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **json datatype can not have default values** in MySQL. Use the `$attributes` instead.

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'interests' => 'array',
];

protected $attributes = [
    'interests' => [],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just if anyone comes accross it, you can do this for json and string:

$table->string('field')->default(json_encode([]));